# Ant design css not loading on next.js build

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using AntD components in my Next project and during development everything works fine, but when I build the project, Ant-Design css does not load properly. I have tried adding "import 'antd/dist/antd.css'" in _app, all the components and pages that use AntD components to no avail. Inspecting the source, for some reason only antd keyframes are loaded in *e.g. antSlideUpIn, antdDrawerFadeIn*

Is there something that I'm missing? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using tailwind? But with tailwind removed it still does not work.

**top of _app.tsx**

```
import '../styles/index.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

**index.css**

```
/* purgecss start ignore */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
/* purgecss end ignore */
```

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am using Tailwind?

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
      parser: 'postcss-scss',
      plugins: [
        'tailwindcss',
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
          [ '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss', {
              content: [
                './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
                './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
              ],
              defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            },
          ] : undefined,
        'postcss-preset-env',
      ],
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: ["./pages/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "gamestreet-teal-1": "#59f5ff",
        "gamestreet-purple-1": "#7774ff",
        "gamestreet-purple-2": "#a98bff",
        "gamestreet-purple-3": "#291749",
        "gamestreet-pink-1": "#ff0ff5",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```